# Oracle SQL get level of a recursive with a subquery

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, subquery, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to get the level in my statement and build a subquery to get it into my statement. When I execute my statement I get the error:

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
> 01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

This is my statement:

```
SELECT 
    a.id, b.identifier, 
    (SELECT level
     FROM buik b, material m
     WHERE b.auftrag = m.auftrag
     START WITH b.identifier = 'B091000656'
     CONNECT BY PRIOR m.istcharge = b.identifier )
FROM aston a, buik b
```

Comment: There is no correlation between your main query and the subquery

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**almost 30 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

A hierarchical query returns multiple rows.
This is the reason for the ORA-01427 error.
I suppose, that you need to rewrite / correct your query, depending on your task:

1. refine the parameters in your subquery so that the correct dataset is returned in 1 row
2. rewrite your sql query correctly.

Additional links:
[SQL Subquery](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/queries007.htm)

[SQL correlated](https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-correlated-subquery/)